# Dynamically choosing column for WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I've got a table that holds columns named "Day1" through to "Day31".

Is there a way I can dynamically choose the correct column to put in a WHERE clause?

I can get the current day, that's no problem, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Your life would be easy with a row per day instead of column per day.

Comment: Yeah i know :') but it's not possible in this instance :P

Comment: Unpivot your data in subquery, use WHERE over unpivoted name field, obtain non-'DayNN' fields data and use it as a filter in outer query WHERE.

Comment: it's all good, i got it sorted :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DATEPART DAY` to retrieve today's day, then build a simple dynamic SQL concatenating that day's value to the column name.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PivotedInfo') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #PivotedInfo

CREATE TABLE #PivotedInfo (
    Day1 INT,
    Day2 INT,
    Day3 INT,
    Day4 INT)

DECLARE @DayToday INT = DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())

DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT
        P.[Day' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @DayToday) + ']
    FROM
        #PivotedInfo AS P '


PRINT (@DynamicSQL)

/*
    SELECT
        P.[Day3]
    FROM
        #PivotedInfo AS P 
*/


EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
```

If you need a general column name as result, you can add an alias:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT
        DailyValue = P.[Day' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @DayToday) + ']
    FROM
        #PivotedInfo AS P '


PRINT (@DynamicSQL)

/*
    SELECT
        DailyValue = P.[Day3]
    FROM
        #PivotedInfo AS P 
*/
```

---

You can avoid using dynamic SQL if you unpivot your columns and then filter where the unpivot column name matches your wanted day. It would be more readable but more expensive operation.

```
INSERT INTO #PivotedInfo (Day1, Day2, Day3, Day4)
VALUES (5, 10, 15, 20)

SELECT
    P.*
FROM
    #PivotedInfo AS I
    UNPIVOT (
        DailyValue FOR Day IN  ([Day1], [Day2], [Day3], [Day4]) -- All day list here
    ) AS P
WHERE
    P.Day = 'Day' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DAY(GETDATE()))
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot

Answer (score 0):

Add the number you get from the current day and add this to the string holding your dynamic query. E.g.:

```
...

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);

...

SET @query = N'SELECT ... WHERE day' + convert(nvarchar, datepart(day, getdate())) + N' = ...;';

...
```